# Qt Application using C++ and QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new to Qt, and am using Qt Creator 2.4.1 for development.

**Question** - Where can I find (or What are the) examples built using QML and C++?

I have been searching and its been not very fruitful. Like I have found examples using pure QML. Or the demo "samegame" uses javascript with QML.

Just to try out, here is some code I wrote in main.cpp -

```
QDeclarativeView view;
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("game", new Game);
view.setSource(QUrl("qml/hangman/main.qml"));

view.show();
```

The **question** related to code - If I were to use C++ and QML, is this how the code in main() is supposed to be?

In the **main.qml** I will make all the different types of buttons, and mouseareas required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.8-snapshot/qdeclarativeexamples.html) examples from Qt documentation. You may see C++ code in most examples.
Usually, the main function is as below:

```
 QApplication app(argc, argv);

 QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
 viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
 viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("path_to_qml"));
 viewer.showExpanded();

 return app.exec();
```

[Extending QML Functionalities using C++](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-extending.html) is good article too.